# ArgumentError too few arguments when trying to test the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I'm trying to learn how to do tests in Rails. I have a `foods_controller` and in the test folder, my `food.yml` is filled with all of the parameters that should be present when creating a new food object and in `foods_controller_test.rb`, the parameters in "should create food" are matching the ones in `food.yml`. When running a test I get this error:

```
ArgumentError: too few arguments
    app/controllers/application_controller.rb:45:in `format'
    app/controllers/application_controller.rb:45:in `authorize'
    test/controllers/foods_controller_test.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <class:FoodsControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/foods_controller_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:FoodsControllerTest>
```

Can anyone exaplain me what is wrong here?

food.yml

```
one:
  name: "Whatever"
  portion: "100g"
  calories: 1
  fat: 1.5
  carb: 1.5
  protein: 1.5
  fiber: 1.5
  sugar: 1.5
  category: "Grains"

two:
  name: "MyString"
  portion: "MyString"
  calories: 1
  fat: 1.5
  carb: 1.5
  protein: 1.5
  fiber: 1.5
  sugar: 1.5
  category: "MyString"
```

foods_controller_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class FoodsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @food = foods(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get :index
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:foods)
  end

  test "should get new" do
    get :new
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create food" do
    assert_difference('Food.count') do
      post :create, food: { calories: @food.calories, carb: @food.carb, category: @food.category, fat: @food.fat, fiber: @food.fiber, name: @food.name, portion: @food.portion, protein: @food.protein, sugar: @food.sugar }
    end

    assert_redirected_to food_path(assigns(:food))
  end

  test "should show food" do
    get :show, id: @food
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should get edit" do
    get :edit, id: @food
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update food" do
    patch :update, id: @food, food: { calories: @food.calories, carb: @food.carb, category: @food.category, fat: @food.fat, fiber: @food.fiber, name: @food.name, portion: @food.portion, protein: @food.protein, sugar: @food.sugar }
    assert_redirected_to food_path(assigns(:food))
  end

  test "should destroy food" do
    assert_difference('Food.count', -1) do
      delete :destroy, id: @food
    end

    assert_redirected_to foods_path
  end
end
```

foods_controller.rb

```
class FoodsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_food, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :authorize, only: [:create, :delete]

  # GET /foods
  # GET /foods.json
  def index
    @foods = Food.order(:name)

    # @foods = @foods.sort_by &:name
    # @users.sort! { |a,b| a.name.downcase <=> b.name.downcase }
    @food_categories = Food::CATEGORIES.keys.sort
    # @current_category ||= params(:category)
    day_selected = params[:day_selected]
    meal_selected = params[:meal_selected]
  end

  # GET /foods/1
  # GET /foods/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /foods/new
  def new
    @food = Food.new
  end

  # GET /foods/1/edit
  def edit

  end

  # POST /foods
  # POST /foods.json
  def create
    @food = Food.new(food_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @food.save
        format.html { redirect_to foods_url, notice: 'Food was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @food }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @food.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /foods/1
  # PATCH/PUT /foods/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @food.update(food_params)
        format.html { redirect_to foods_url, notice: 'Food was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @food }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @food.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /foods/1
  # DELETE /foods/1.json
  def destroy
    #current_user.entries.where(food_id: "#{@food.id}").delete_all
    @food.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to foods_url, notice: 'Food was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_food
      @food = Food.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def food_params
      params.require(:food).permit(:name, :portion, :calories, :fat, :carb, :protein,
                                    :fiber, :sugar, :category, :added_by, :cholesterol,
                                    :potassium, :sodium, :trans_fat, :monounsaturated_fat,
                                    :polyunsaturated_fat, :saturated_fat)
    end

end
```

food.rb

```
class Food < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  CATEGORIES = { "Dairy & Eggs" => "Dairy",
                "Meat & Fish" => "Animal",
                "Fruits & Vegetables" => "Plant",
                "Nuts, beans & legumes" => "Nuts",
                "Grains" => "Grains",
                "Drinks" => "Beverages",
                "Sweets & Candy" => "Sweets",
                "Oils & Fats" => "Oils",
                "Other" => "Other" }

  validates :name, presence: true

  validates :portion, presence: true

  validates :calories, presence: true

  validates :fat, presence: true

  validates :carb, presence: true

  validates :protein, presence: true

  validates :category, presence: true

end
```

Comment: HI there, you have a before_filter authorize in your controller. So in your test case too you will have to authorize before you create. Are you using devise? Then try using the devise helpers for testing. That will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the format in the test example, in your case `json` or `html`.

```
post :create, format: json, food: { ... }
```